# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null when run on browser

Tags: javascript, html

I want to display today's date on the input text. But why am I receiving the error after I run on the browser? Is there anything wrong with the code.

**HTML**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html >
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
 <title>Insert title here</title>
 <script  type=text/javascript>


 var today = new Date();
 var dd = today.getDate();
 var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
 var yyyy = today.getFullYear();


 if(dd<10) {
dd = '0'+dd
} 

if(mm<10) {
mm = '0'+mm}

 today= mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
 document.getElementById("today1").value=today;
 </script>
<body>

<input id="today1" value="">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you running your javascript only once the page has loaded? (i.e move your `<script>` to the bottom of your `<body>`). My guess is that your javascript is trying to get the input element but it doesn't know about it since your page hasn't fully loaded yet.

Comment: post complete html

Comment: @NickParsons Oh Thank you! It works after I've moved it.

Comment: @fatinamirah no worries. You can add a page load event handler to your javascript which will do this for you so you don't need to move it. Some of the answers show how to do this :)

Comment: Yes Sir. I've done all the given answer. They all work like charm! Thank you everyone :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run your javaScript only after the DOM is loaded.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
 var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();


if(dd<10) {
    dd = '0'+dd
} 

if(mm<10) {
    mm = '0'+mm}

 today= mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
 document.getElementById("today1").value=today;
});
```

Comment: @fatinamirah check the answered.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is running before the DOM is ready. Wrap your code with [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded). This will ensure that the code will be executed after all the initial HTML has been completely loaded and parsed.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  // your code here
});
```

**Working Code Example:**

```html
<script  type=text/javascript>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

    var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();


    if(dd<10) {
    dd = '0'+dd
    } 

    if(mm<10) {
    mm = '0'+mm}

    today= mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
    document.getElementById("today1").value=today;
  });
</script>


<input id="today1" value="">
```

Answer (score 0):

the code at this link might be helpful to you [here](https://js.do/vachhaninimit/256184)